# Question about meaning of "till you dropped"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Should you have shopped till you dropped?

I actually have no idea what it really means. 
But my guess is the word "till" might mean "because"

> Considering you are not rich, was it wise to buy so many things with your small salary?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/what-is-the-difference-between-till-and-until

Comment: You post lots of questions but do not seem to accept any answers as correct. I will feel more motivated to help you if I knew that our answers were really helping you.

Answer (score 2):

*Shop till you drop* is an idiom. The literal meaning is that you shopped to the point of physical exhaustion. Colloquially it just means you did a lot of shopping and are tired because of it.

*Till* is just a contraction of *until*. That might help you to make sense of it.